# What is the origin of all the technology?

Tags: tales-from-the-loop

In *Tales from the Loop*, there is a variety of techology that can produce supernatural effects. 
Some of the technology was clearly created by Russ, namely all the robotics. Specifically, George's robot arm, and the First and Second androids.

However, what about the rest?

- Is the Eclipse something Russ made or a natural phenomenon?
- Did Russ make things like the Echo Sphere, the Body Switching sphere, or the time-stop device? It seems strange that he would make such dangerous inventions and leave them lying around in the woods to rust or cause havoc, or that he would make such *useful* inventions and not use them for further research.

In  short, who made all the weird "technology" that is around the Loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've enjoyed watching "Tales from The Loop," and I am happy to share my answer your question, yet I realize it may not be what you're seeking.

My view is that in some tales, the ***origin*** of extraordinary objects appearing in the stories is central, and that in other tales, it isn't relevant -- and that is the situation of the extraordinary objects you mention.

Arthur C. Clarke is known many writing accomplishments, including his three laws, the third and most famous of which is: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

In the case of the extraordinary object, the alien monolith, in A. C. Clarke's short story "The Sentinel" (which was the basis for the movie "2001: A Space Odyssey") its origin *was* central to those story lines.

Recall the English fairy tale, "Jack and the Beanstalk," in which there are a number of magical items: including the magic beans, the goose that lays golden eggs, and the magic harp that plays by itself. The origin of these magic items is not explained -- it is irrelevant to the story.

The devices you mentioned in "Tales from the Loop" are also examples of two technological devices so advanced that they truly are indistinguishable from magic, so they are also extraordinary objects.

My analysis is that the origin of the devices is unexplained simply because it *is not* central to these stories. What is important is how the characters react to them. So, Tales from the Loop is more about how the characters react to the extraordinary objects than a quest for their origins.

---

Here is a link, simply for your enjoyment, to the works of the great Italian sculptor Arnaldo Pomodoro.

He often explores the theme of discarded alien technology / objects, especially his series "sphere within a sphere."

[Wikipedia page for Arnaldo Pomodoro's sculture series "Sphere within a Sphere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_Within_Sphere)